# How can I match a specific type of URL with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match/extract a specific type of URL's from input. I am trying to match extract everything that starts with "https://google.com" and everything after it.
For example,
if the input was "!command [https://google.com/?randomstuff+something=="](https://google.com/?randomstuff+something==%22)

Output: https://google.com/?randomstuff+something==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex is pretty simple, you just need to add `.*` after the group you want to catch: `https://google.com/.*`

`.` capture any one character. `.*` capture 0 or more of any character.

You can test your regex query here: https://regex101.com/

There is also some documentation to explain what you can do and what to write.

Comment: hello, thanks for answering! Do you know what is the regex expression I can use in the script, or to test it out in regex editor? I apologize for the request as I am new to regex.

Comment: On the page, your test string could be: `!command https://google.com/?randomstuff+something==` and the Regular Expression is `https://google.com/.*`. You can enter more test string and play with the tool to look at the different output. You can do multiple group with parentheses `()`, etc.